# With EF Core 7.0 when SplitToTable, SplitTableBuilder.Property does not accept a lambda

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-7.0

The example from Microsoft looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(
    entityBuilder =>
    {
        entityBuilder
            .ToTable("Customers")
            .SplitToTable(
                "PhoneNumbers",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerId");
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.PhoneNumber);
                })
            .SplitToTable(
                "Addresses",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerId");
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.Street);
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.City);
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.PostCode);
                    tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.Country);
                });
    });
```

`tableBuilder.Property()` should accept an Expression<Func<Customer, string>> but it's only allowing me to enter a string. So I need to use this:

```
tableBuilder.Property("Id")
```

Instead of:

```
tableBuilder.Property(customer => customer.Id)
```

I think I may be missing an `using` directive but I can't seem to figure out which.

Does anyone know what would cause his issue?

Comment: You have to use `.SplitToTable<PhoneNumber>`, otherwise EF do not know properties from which class to use.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work. The method is `.SplitToTable<Customer>()` and specifying <Customer> is not required.

Comment: I do not understand that. You have to specify `.SplitToTable<PhoneNumber>` and `.SplitToTable<Address>`. What do not work? There are two overloads of `SplitToTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved itself. Even thought I didn't make any change I stop getting build errors. VS is now excepting a lambda as the parameter.